# Making the footer stick at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

What I really want is to make the footer at the bottom of the page stick while rest of the page scrolls. None of the answers here I find satisfactory. So please if someone can help.

**EDIT**

Actually I am dynamically modifying the DOM elements of body using javascript. So I dont have a div named "content". i.e. the structure of my html file would be like this :

```
<body> 

---- body ----- 

<div id="footer">
  My Dynamic Footer
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: Guys I would like modify my question. Actually I am dynamically modifying the DOM elements of body using javascript. So I dont have a div named "content". i.e. the structure of my html file would be like this :
<body>
     ---- body -----
     <div id="footer">My Dynamic Footer</div>
</body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: fixed;` is the only solution in your case  [**see this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6AWW4/2/)

**CSS**

```
    html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 3em;
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

**HTML**

My Dynamic Footer

**Note** : In the fiddle, un-comment the text to see the footer stretching the height after a dynmic height content!!

**==========================EDIT==========================**

as per your comment, here is the [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6AWW4/3/)

**==========================jQuery EDIT==========================**

Using **jQuery** you can achieve the target...[**see fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6AWW4/5/)

JQ required :

```
$( "<div class='space'></div>" ).insertBefore( "#footer" );
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.space
{
    height:6em; /* this is problem solver */
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 3em;
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

**==========================Final EDIT using JAVASCRIPT==========================**

[**javascript demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3D9C3/)

Keeping above HTMl markup same, use below *javascript* to solve your problem :

```
var link = document.getElementById("footer")
var new_node = document.createElement("div");
new_node.className="space";
new_node.innerHTML = "";
link.parentNode.insertBefore(new_node, link.nextSibling);
```

Comment: Still the body content is not fully shown. It is getting hidden by the footer.

Comment: @PragmaticProgrammer : your `footer` is `fixed`, this means that it will remain in its position and any content which has greater height will **underly** the footer....you only wanted **fixed footer with scrollable page**....do u have nythng else in mind???

Comment: Any content that has greater height is being underlied the footer but full content is not shown. Check it properly!

Comment: @PragmaticProgrammer : i checked it properly...now its your turn to understand properly whats happening....see the content of the body will underly the footer when height is exceeded because the content has `body` as a parent and not any `div`....only solution is to either `wrap` the content in div( *like my first demo*) or manually give `<br/>` to create the necessary gap in the end....try to imagine whats happening after removing the `footer` for a minute!! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#footer { 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: The footer sticks there but it should not slide over the content.

Comment: @Pragmatic My answer and the link provided in the comment covers that.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would add is a `margin-bottom` so that your footer doesn't hide any content when it reaches the bottom of the page.

```
.content {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IhirOjO/1/edit)